# Adding decimal separators to a YouTube view count retrieved via API

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-api

I'm trying to retrieve a YouTube view count for a specific video on my Wordpress site. I'm not a coder but I've managed to get it working using this code:

```
<div id="viewCount" style="display: inline-block;"></div>
 <script>
       let getviewCount = () => {
        fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=Cemk32wKN_k&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`)
        .then(response => {
            return response.json()
        })
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            viewCount.innerHTML = data["items"][0].statistics.viewCount;
        })      
    }
    getviewCount(); 
    </script>
```

The final touch I'd like to add is decimal separators so instead of the number looking like this:

**13526897**

It looks like this:

**13,526,897**

Based on some research here I think I need to use a function similar to this:

```
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

But I don't know how to code, so combining these two ideas is beyond my ability right now.

If anyone wouldn't mind showing me how to do it, I'd be extremely grateful!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Congrats on your first venture into programming! copy and paste the function definition for `numberWithCommas` before the word `let`.

To use the function you added, simply call `numberWithCommas` with `data["items"][0].statistics.viewCount` inside the parenthesis.

In all, your new code would look like the following:

```js
<div id="viewCount" style="display: inline-block;"></div>
 <script>
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
       let getviewCount = () => {
        fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=Cemk32wKN_k&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`)
        .then(response => {
            return response.json()
        })
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            viewCount.innerHTML = numberWithCommas(data["items"][0].statistics.viewCount);
        })      
    }
    getviewCount(); 
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has built-in functions for this

`Intl.NumberFormat()` function

It will format the number depending on the user's default browser language.

```js
var number = 1234567890;
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat().format(number));
```

Will output

1,234,567,890 for US clients

1.234.567.890 for German clients

Answer (score 0):

```
let num = '13,526,897';
    num = num.replace(/\,/g, ''); 
    num = parseInt(num, 10);
```

You can create a function if you want to use this piece of code again:

```
function parseNumber(number) {
   return parseInt(number.replace(/\,/g,''), 10); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you should do...

```
    <div id="viewCount" style="display: inline-block;"></div>
 <script>
       let getviewCount = () => {
        fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=Cemk32wKN_k&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`)
        .then(response => {
            return response.json()
        })
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            numberWithCommas(viewCount.innerHTML = data["items"][0].statistics.viewCount);
        })      
    }
    getviewCount(); 

    function numberWithCommas(x) {
       return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
     }
    </script>
```